# SHA256 breaking personalization strings in email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, crypto

We are currently using this code block in an email

```
%%[
VAR @email, @customer_no, @secret, @url, @hash
SET @email = "%%email%%"
SET @customer_no = "%%customer_no%%"
SET @secret = "<secretkey>"
SET @hash = SHA256(Concat(@email,@customer_no,@secret))
SET @url = Concat("<CompanyURL>?a=",@email,"&amp;c=",@customer_no,"&amp;h=",@hash)
]%%
```

And vardumping with

```
%%=v(@email)=%%
%%=v(@customer_no)=%%
%%=v(@secret)=%%
%%=v(@hash)=%%
```

The url that we get has both the email address and the customer number correctly, but the hash is wrong.  Looking at the vardump, the email and customer_no were returning "%%email%%" and "%%customer_no%%" respectively instead of the personalizations.  The hash should be "emailcustomer_nosecret" no spaces between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing inline and block AMPscript.  No need for the double-percent notation in your block:

```
%%[

VAR @email, @customer_no, @secret, @url, @hash
SET @email = AttributeValue("email")
SET @customer_no = AttributeValue("customer_no")
SET @secret = "<secretkey>"
SET @hash = SHA256(Concat(@email,@customer_no,@secret))
SET @url = Concat("<CompanyURL>a=", @email, "&amp;c=", @customer_no, "&amp;h=", @hash)

]%%
```

Comment: Ah, I was under the impression that the double-percents were needed for any personalization strings, inside a block or outside.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not entirely sure why the personalization strings didn't work inside the SHA256 function, but replacing the personalization strings with Lookups made it work.

Final Code:

```
%%[
VAR @email, @customer_no, @secret, @url, @hash
SET @email = Lookup("DEtest","email","email",_SubscriberKey)
SET @customer_no = Lookup("DEtest","customer_no","email",_SubscriberKey)
SET @secret = "<SECRET KEY>"
SET @hash = SHA256(Concat(@email,@customer_no,@secret))
SET @url = Concat("<URL>a=",@email,"&amp;c=",@customer_no,"&amp;h=",@hash)
]%%
```